# Vectorization of Loop in R: cash flow of a bond

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

I need to calculate the amortization (debt repayment) values in $ for a bond that amortizes in an irregular fashion. As an example, I created the following amortization scheme:

- Period 1: no amortization
- Period 2: amortizes 10% of the debt
- Period 3: amortizes 30% of the **remaining** debt
- Period 4: amortizes 100% of the **remaining** debt

Below, the code for the calculations suitable for the example described above, considering a debt of $1000, using a for-loop.

```
# Vector with amortization values (in % of outstanding balance)
prc_amortization = c(0, 10, 30, 100)

# Value for initial balance
initial_balance = 1000

# Dataframe
df = data.frame(initial_balance = c(initial_balance, rep(NA, 3)),
                prc_amortization = prc_amortization,
                amortization = NA,
                final_balance = NA)

# Calculation of amortization values in $, leading to updated balances
for (i in 1:4) {
  df$amortization[i] = df$initial_balance[i]*df$prc_amortization[i]/100
  df$final_balance[i] = df$initial_balance[i] - df$amortization[i]
  if (i<4) {df$initial_balance[i+1] = df$final_balance[i]}
}

# Results
df
  initial_balance prc_amortization amortization final_balance
1            1000                0            0          1000
2            1000               10          100           900
3             900               30          270           630
4             630              100          630             0
```

Since these calculations will me made a large number of times, I feel the need to have this code running as fast as possible.

Is there a way to have these calculations done in a vectorized way?

The tricky part here is that, for any given period, I need to know the initial balance in order to calculate the amortization in $.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that your amortization schedule is *relative to the previous period*. You need to find an *effective* or *absolute* amortization relative to the pre-period balance.

For example, the amortization in the second period is 10% of the remaining balance, which is still 100% of the initial balance. The third period is 30% of the remaining balance, which is 90% (after the 10% deduction), so the absolute amortization of the first balance is 90%×30%=27%. Similarly for the fourth period. This can be done programmatically/verbosely as:

```
effective_prc_amortization <- numeric(length(prc_amortization))
for (i in seq_along(effective_prc_amortization)) {
  prevsum <- if (i == 1) 1 else 1 - sum(effective_prc_amortization[1:(i-1)])
  effective_prc_amortization[i] <- prevsum * prc_amortization[i]/100
}
effective_prc_amortization
# [1] 0.00 0.10 0.27 0.63
```

From this, you can easily calculate an arbitrary period only knowing the initial balance, not needing the previous period's balance.

```
# amortization
effective_prc_amortization * initial_balance
# [1]   0 100 270 630
# final_balance
initial_balance - cumsum(effective_prc_amortization * initial_balance)
# [1] 1000  900  630    0
```

Other views:

```
# percentage remaining
cumprod(1 - c(0,10,30,100)/100)
# [1] 1.00 0.90 0.63 0.00

# value remaining
1000 * cumprod(1 - c(0,10,30,100)/100)
# [1] 1000  900  630    0
```